# Is this a proper algorithm that would accept graph G if it's connected?

Tags: algorithm

I wanted to ask and see if this suffices in creating a polynomial time algorithm given a Graph P? Just want to double check.

On input (P,u,v) where P is an undirected graph with nodes u and v:

1. Create a list D of every edge in graph P with numbers from x_0 to x_k.
2. Select node u as the starting node. Utilizing BFS, traverse through the graph until the current node is the initial u value.
3. Repeat with using x_0 onwards through the list until x_k is used.
4. If BFS completes, accept. Otherwise, reject.

I believe my problem lets with the accept/rejection condition but what would it be in this case?

Comment: I also find several things about this question confusing.  One not mentioned by o11c: What do you mean by "If BFS completes"?  How could it not complete?

Comment: Well when I wrote it I wasn't sure what would've been the conditional statement that would denote success at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't make sense in a lot of ways, but from what I can tell, no.

Your step 2 will (slowly) find a *cycle*, which is not useful.

I have no clue what step 3 is supposed to be and your variable `v` is unused (and having `u` as as parameter doesn't make sense).

For an directed graph, you need to specify whether you want to check for weak connectivity (like a undirected graph) or strong connectivity.

For weak connectivity, you need to:

1. Take as input a graph `G`
2. Create a local, empty, set `S` for seen nodes.
3. Do a depth first search (*including* backwards links - watch your algorithmic complexity with how you look them up!) from some node, adding each node to `S` as you visit it, and skipping edges that lead from the current node to a node in `S` during iteration. (You can use a breadth-first search if you allocate an additional data set for the frontier)
4. Check whether `S` has the same number of nodes as `G`.

For strong connectivity, you need to check that the graph is connected regardless of which node you set at. There's probably a way to do this more efficiently than repeating the above for every node.

An example graph (consider this from any starting node):

```
1 -> 2
2 -> 3
3 -> 1
3 -> 4
4 -> 5
5 -> 6
6 -> 4
```

Comment: Well I did try to create an empty record for seen nodes, thats what I considered D. But I can see why depth would be more useful in such a situation. What do you mean by an additional data set for the fronteir? Since the example given is an undirected graph, wouldn't the strength of connectivity be irrelevant?

Comment: @marcoquezada it's just a standard property of BFS: you need to keep track both of nodes you've visited and nodes that have been neighbors of nodes you've visited. DFS is almost always easier, so just ignore it; BFS is useful if you're dealing with infinite graphs, or if you want the shortest path.

Comment: I see, I see. I'm unsure what you meant by watching the complexity with how I look it up. How much of a different would it make?

Comment: @marcoquezada a huge difference. Doing a reverse-lookup directly is n lookups at O(n) per lookup, so O(n^2) total. Building (or extending) an map is O(n log n), plus n lookups with cust O(n log n), so O(n log n)